# configure redis on windows high performance

Tags: windows, redis

We are trying to setup Redis on Windows. Any time we take thread profile from our server we see time spend on Redis.SocketManager.WriteAllQueues. Also we see heavy network usage on the cache server.

We have lots of concurrent users logging in and we dont need redis to persist the data.

What is the right way to configure redis on a production server?

Currently I found configuring these values might improve. Is there any other settings I need to change to get the best performances?

- Increase tcp-backlog from 511 to 65536
- persistence-available no
- Increase maxclients from 10000 to 20000  (is this required)
- Should I change the timeout from 0, if so what would be a good number?

Any help appreciated

[image: Thread Profile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- disable bgsave in redis.conf
- timeout of 0 is ok

Comment: I still think that I have not configured it right. Since most days around the same time I see performance issue on the site. I was not able to see a setting called bgsave in redis.windows-service.config file. Or is there anything I need to do.

Comment: its called save you can set it in the running instance: https://redis.io/commands/config-set